# What was the name of the Mac application to analyze sleeping patterns?

Tags: mac, software-rec, sleep

I remember that about two or three years ago, there was an application that ran on OS X (panther for sure) that you could install on a laptop next to your bed and it will analyze your sleeping patterns, noise, movement, etc. All through the cam/mic.

Does anybody remember the name of that application? I couldn’t find any reference to it. It simply vanished.

Comment: Very interesting, but I doubt such thing exists.

Comment: It did exit and it didn’t promise “magical results”. It would just show you graphics about how you sleep. A pity I couldn’t find it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

A good website to look for Mac software is [i use this](http://osx.iusethis.com/).

I found this app there: [Dream Recorder](http://osx.iusethis.com/app/dreamrecorder)

> Dream Recorder measures your sleep
>   states by detecting your motions all
>   along the night, using a enhanced
>   night vision mode for iSight
>   cameras... It wakes you up at the best
>   moment of your morning sleep cycle,
>   and provides dream feed-back and voice
>   recording capabilities. Body motions
>   are related to the sleep phases. They
>   occur before and after dreams and are
>   almost absent during deep sleep
>   phases. You are awaken for very short
>   instants during the night, without
>   even noticing. Dream Recorder uses
>   this motion profile to reconstruct the
>   sleep cycles.

Comment: Yes, IUT kicks ass. Welcome to Super User!

Answer (score 0):

This [iPhone](http://www.pugilator.com/tests/analyze-your-sleep-pattern-with-the-iphone-and-sleep-cycle-app/) app apparently uses the accelerometer to monitor your motion during the night.
[ZZZ Checker](http://www.geek.com/articles/gadgets/zzz-checker-helps-analyze-your-sleep-patterns-2009079/) uses IR video and sound but it's a standalone device.  I found several other dedicated devices but not an OS-X app.

Comment: Thanks for the info, the app has disappeared from the face of the planet. Which is very weird. :S